# express types doesn't work well in TS playground

Tags: typescript, express, typescript-playground

Try making a demo for the TS type of `express`. Also, follow the Type Acquisition guide of TS Playground to control the version of the types which are imported into the Playground using `// types: npm_tag_or_version`.

Both versions specified, neither work.

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'; // types: 4.18.2
// import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'; // types: 4.17.7

const app = express();

const authenticate = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    next();
};

app.post('/create', authenticate, (req: Request, res: Response) => { });
```

Got error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): Express', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.
      Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
        Type 'NextFunction | undefined' is not assignable to type 'NextFunction'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NextFunction'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): Express', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler'.(2769)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAUwB5iggzugNHA3nAJQQEcBXDGHI9SAO3QRwDlkYAxU2gYxmAlrgBfOADMoEEHADkyVBnRSA3HAD0KuDACeYDAC44AFgB0ARgAcRgEwBYAFBq4oSLEQo0mHPiJkKVDHQZmVg5uXn4hUXFJGTd5JVV1LR10fWMTAHYjdLs7Ln50eABDMDA4AF5XOUwACgBKRRzbPPoi0hgACwRaXi5CmARyuGq0Yn1vcgKcdzH-fMY4WlZ9FiR2Th4+WlrygD48OzhDhdY6httBM7tisCNIAuqpFS40PoQpHEK2zu7gXv6cYYkGY+SZwaaEWb0BDbMp7fCCep2IA)

TS version: 5.1.3

Comment: Optional param for next seems to resolve the problem

Comment: @Lesiak I don't think the `next` function is optional for express middleware. It's weird.

Answer (score 2):

Optional param for `next` seems to resolve the problem:

```ts
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

const app = express();

const authenticate = (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction) => {
    if (next) {
      next();
    }
};

app.post('/create', authenticate, (req: Request, res: Response) => { });
```

It seems TS Playground gets confused about `express-serve-static-core` types.

When hovering over type it pulls in [@types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts)

```ts
export interface RequestHandler<
    P = ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
    LocalsObj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line callable-types (This is extended from and can't extend from a type alias in ts<2.2)
    (
        req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, LocalsObj>,
        res: Response<ResBody, LocalsObj>,
        next: NextFunction,
    ): void;
}
```

But when navigating into app.post, it pulls in [express-serve-static-core/express-serve-static-core.d.ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express-serve-static-core?activeTab=code)

```ts
interface RequestHandler {
  (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction): any;
}
```

IMHO this is a bug in Playground